# What Index Can I Create For This Query?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE [Cache].[Marker](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SubID] [varchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [ReadTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [EquipmentID] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [Sequence] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

And the following indexes:

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Marker_EquipmentID_ReadTime_SubID] ON [Cache].[Marker] 
(
    [EquipmentID] ASC,
    [ReadTime] ASC,
    [SubID] ASC
)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Marker_Id] ON [Cache].[Marker] 
(
    [ID] ASC
)
INCLUDE ( [EquipmentID]) 

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Marker_SubID] ON [Cache].[Marker] 
(
    [SubID] ASC
)
INCLUDE ( [EquipmentID],[ReadTime])
```

I'm executing the following query:

```
Declare @EquipmentId varchar(50)

SELECT TOP 1 
    C44DistId,
    C471DistId,
    C473RightLotId
From Cache.vwMarker m
    INNER JOIN Cache.vwCoaterRecipe AS cr ON cr.MarkerId = m.ID AND M.EquipmentID = @EquipmentId
Order By m.Id Desc
```

The query plan looks as follows:

[image]

The Marker table has roughly 7M rows, so the scan is pretty expensive. There are only 24 unique EquipmentId values in the 7M rows, which is probably why a scan is being done.

This query often takes 40+ seconds to execute, depending on server load. I've been trying to think of a way (by creating some sort of index) to get SQL Server to do a seek on the Marker table. I haven't been able to come up with anything. Perhaps there isn't a way, but I thought I'd ask first.

Answer (score 1):

The only index on the `Marker` table which includes both the `EquipmentID` and `Id` columns is the `IX_Marker_Id`. Since this index doesn't have `EquipmentID` as the first column, you can't seek on it; you have to scan the index in reverse order to find the first entry with a matching `EquipmentID`.

Something like this might help:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Marker_EquipmentID_Id] ON [Cache].[Marker] 
(
   [EquipmentID] ASC,
   [ID] DESC
)
```

---

**EDIT:** Of course, your clustered index includes both columns, but with only 24 different `EquipmentID` values, it would have to scan over 290000 rows to find the maximum `Id`. By scanning the `IX_Marker_Id` index in reverse, it can stop as soon as it finds a matching `EquipmentID`, which will probably be faster.